# Python - share class inputs from parent class to children class

Tags: python, class

Let's say I have a parent class and multiple children classes:

```
class Parent(object):

    def _init__(self, generation):
        self.generation = generation

class Child1(Parent):

    def __init__(self, dimension, generation):
        super(Child1, self).__init__(generation)

        self.dimension = dimension
        print('child1')

class Child2(Parent):

    def __init__(self, dimension, generation):
        super(Child1, self).__init__(generation)

        self.dimension = dimension
        print('child2')
```

After I have already defined all my children classes, I realise that I would like to add a command to the `__init__` of any class. Namely, I would like them to execute the method `plotting` which I define in `Parent`:

```
class Parent(object):

    def _init__(self, generation, plot = 0):
        self.generation = generation
        self.plot = plot
        if self.plot = 1: self.plotting


    def plotting(self):
        print('plotting here')
```

--

How can I avoid having to give the argument `plot = 0` to each child class?

Basically I would just like to now call `a = Child1(dimension, generation, plot = 1)`

Comment: huh? can you try to explain what you are trying to do in another way? I didnt follow your existing explanation.

Comment: I would like `plotting` to be executed when I make an instance of any of the children classes. Is there a way to achieve this by just modifying the parent class?

Comment: @SuperCiocia yes cal the `plotting` method in parent init. `self.plotting()`

Comment: @SuperCiocia no, I don't think there is. Some IDEs might have refactoring tools to do this automatically for you, but the child-class `__init__` signatures have to be re-written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Parent(object):

    def _init__(self, generation,plot=0):
        self.generation = generation
        if plot == 1:
           self.do_plot()

    def do_plot(self):
        print("You are doing something here i guess...")
```

then in your child init you just pass in the plot ...

```
class Child1(Parent):

    def __init__(self, dimension, generation,plot=1):
        super(Child1, self).__init__(generation,plot)
        self.dimension = dimension
```

you could use kwargs to allow for more expansion in the future

```
class Parent(object):

    def _init__(self, generation,**kwargs):
        plot = kwargs.get("plot",0)
        self.generation = generation
        if plot == 1:
           self.do_plot()

    def do_plot(self):
        print("You are doing something here i guess...")

class Child1(Parent):

        def __init__(self, dimension, generation,**kwargs):
            super(Child1, self).__init__(generation,**kwargs)
            self.dimension = dimension
```

if you just want it to always plot ... just always call plot in the Parent...

if you want it to default to 1 if nothing is passed then change `plot=0` to `plot=1` in the parent constructor

Comment: I think the problem is they don't want to modify the derived classes to accept the new `plot` argument. I think they are SOL

Comment: Basically, they want their child-classes to magically accept the `plot` argument without having to re-write them. Again, I think they are SOL, although, maybe IDE's will have refactoring support for this use-case.

Comment: yeah ok I get it now ... so basically ... they wish they had accepted kwargs originally ...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga maybe some trickery with `__new__` on the parent class ? ... but it would really mess with anyone who had to deal with it later (tbh im skeptical its even possible... i tried a little bit)